# Remove all rows where column 2 has value that is not in column 1

Tags: pyspark

I have a large dataframe in pyspark. I want to remove the rows in the dataframe where column2 has a value that is not present in column 1.

```
ids = df.select("column1").distinct()


filtered_df = df.join(ids, on="column2", how="left_anti")
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are facing?

Comment: In the join, when you write `on="column2"` spark will try to find a column name as "column2" in both dfs but ids df do not have such field. try to change it to something like `on=df.column2 == ids.columns1`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have limitations, one of the good approaches is using spark sql and create this logic there.

Something like the code below:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_your_temp_view_name")

fitered_df = spark.sql(
    """
SELECT a.*
FROM vw_your_temp_view_name a
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_1
    FROM vw_your_temp_view_name
) b
ON a.COLUMN_2 = b.COLUMN_1"""
)
```

With this code, the values that exist in column 2 will be checked with the values in column 1 and in case of a match, these values will be returned.